# Plot in Flipped Java Coordinates

Tags: spatstat

I would like to plot a ppp object from a particle analysis in ImageJ from a greyscale image with size imageSizeX, imageSizeY of point objects Particles$X, Particles$Y in flipped Java coordinates (y0 = top-left).
I have a kind of working solution (example with customization):

```
library(spatstat)

X <- ppp(Particles$X, Particles$Y, c(0, imageSizeX), c(0, imageSizeY))
plot(x = 0, y = 0, xlim = c(0, imageSizeX), ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0), type = "n", main = "Density", 
    asp = 1, axes = F, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
plot(density(X), xlim = c(1, imageSizeX), ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0), add = T)
plot(X, axes = TRUE, xlim = c(1, imageSizeX), ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0), add = T)
axis(1)
axis(2, las = 2)
```

which results in the following plot (which omits the legend):

[image]

However I need to create an empty plot command with the flipped coordinates (ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0)) and then have to add the spatstat plots.

If I try to plot:

```
library(spatstat)
X <- ppp(Particles$X, Particles$Y, c(0, imageSizeX), c(0, imageSizeY))
plot(density(X), xlim = c(1, imageSizeX), ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0))
plot(X, axes = TRUE, xlim = c(1, imageSizeX), ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0), add = T)
axis(1)
axis(2, las = 2)
```

the coordinates are not plotted flipped (ylim = c(imageSizeY, 0)):

[image]

Is there a way to flip the plot coordinates in spatstat without a first defining plot command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `plot.ppp`. I have fixed it in the current development version of `spatstat`, version `1.46-1.010` available from [the spatstat repository on GitHub](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat)

In the current version of `spatstat` on CRAN (`1.46-1`) the plot method for windows, `plot.owin`, does recognise `xlim, ylim` as you would like, while `plot.ppp` does not. So if X is a point pattern, you can do

```
W <- Window(X)
plot(W, xlim=rev(W$xrange), main="The title")
plot(X, add=TRUE, ...)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the fast fix and reply!

Comment: Just a minor typo in the window version for a flipped y coordinate: 

plot(W, ylim=rev(W$yrange), main="The title")